# Is possible configurate database services with parameter from form?

Tags: orbeon

Please, I'm needing configurate the database services and parameter, this last case the parameter should come from form (/form/usuario):

```
SELECT name,usuario,lastname FROM Cordloc 
WHERE usuario=<sql:param type="xs:string" select="/form/usuario"/>
```

I think that sentences maybe is not correct, can you help me?.

In the actions, I configurated "Set Response Selection Control Items" with the next values:

```
Items=/response/row
Label=nombre
Value=nombre
```

Many thank.

Comment: Could you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812144/extract-value-from-form-and-send-to-database-service-how-a-parameter-filter), and my answer to it?
It seems to me that you're having a very similar issue. In particular, the value of the `select` attribute must be empty. And of course, just let me know if my answer to that question doesn't completely resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, I try replicate you recomendation.

Comment: Many thanks Alessandro , I tried you recomendation and Its is working !!!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it helped!