# Extract value from form and send to database service how a parameter (filter)

Tags: mysql, database, forms, orbeon

In my configuration, I try the next comand (BD mysql):

```
SELECT user, name, lastname FROM Cordloc 
where user=<sql:param type="xs:string" select="/form/section-1/usuario"/>
```

This database service is conect to drowpdown, but when I incluye the sentence `"where user=<sql:param type="xs:string" select="/form/section-1/usuario"/>"`, 
this it's not  working.

I try the show en drowdown name user, but filter with user login orbeon (in the table is same value "orbeon").

Please, can your help me with that.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an XPath expression, such as `/form/section-1/usuario`, in the query. Instead, the value of the `select` attribute *must* be left empty (as mentioned in [1. Set a service parameter](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html#1-set-a-service-parameter)).

Instead, you "feed" the value to the service from the action. In the *Actions Editor*, under *Set Database Service Parameters*, you can say that the value from a given field should be used for a parameter of your SQL query.